# Total not updating correctly on Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I had a very basic question regarding one of my documents and I need your help.

I have attached the document to this post on a One Drive link, that has the comments in regards to the output I require.

https://1drv.ms/x/s!Aojtb-lU1PMexhrQrkc3YkXAZD4n

The Groom pays the total value excluding the what's under "Henna Cost". I am struggling to get the right values under "Total for Groom" and "Total for Bride" whenever I update/reduce values in the "Paid by Groom" and "Paid by Bride".

For example in this picture, [Excel Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSvEv.jpg), under "Decor Total", if I update the "Paid by Groom" from 500 to 3500, the "Total for Groom" becomes £1500, whilst the "Total for Groom" should be "£0".

I have added comments to the cells in the document for further guidance. I believe what I am trying to achieve is quite self-explanatory but I might be making a silly mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have your maths incorrect,

Cell B5 in your example should be, =(A5-D5)/2-E5

Cell C5 (for bride) should be, =(A5-D5)/2-F5

This would distinguish the cost paid for by the bride and the groom.

Obviously repeat this formula for all the respective Total for groom total for bride.